# Firebase data not showing up in Analytics

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Im trying to send data to Google Analytics using the Firebase SDK and Tag Manager SDK. I was able to see data in Firebase console on the Debug View but im not being able to see it on Google Analytics.

[Firebase Debug View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdRYm.png)

On xCode console i see lines like:

> ```
> 2017-06-30 15:17:26.113 AnalyticsExample[6365:441408] GoogleTagManager info: Sending universal analytics hit: {
> "&t" = screenview;
> "&tid" = "UA-99248086-1";
> ```

I set up a general tag just to be able to see some data on Analytics

[general tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7eLK.png)

But i cant see anything on the real time view of Analytics.
I already added the container folder with the .json file, the GoogleService-info.plist and changed IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED to YES.
Maybe im missing something ...

pods versions are:

> Firebase (4.0.3)
>   FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.2)
>   FirebaseCore (4.0.3)
>   FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.0)
>   GoogleAnalytics (3.17.0)
>   GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
>   GoogleTagManager (6.0.0)
>   GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.1)
>   GoogleUtilities (1.3.2)